# Creating gallery from folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image-gallery

I have created a gallery of images, thumbnails that when you click on them the large image is replaced with the image you have clicked on. Currently I have to write each file in html and create a seperate JS script for each file. This is an example of my current code:

Gallery:

```
        <img id="bigPicMarie" src="assets/Images/MariePeterWeddingImages/Edited/KJ4V7314edit.jpg" alt="banner" />
        <div class="captionBox">
            <p id="captionText"></p>
        </div>

        </div> <!-- end of bigPicMarieContainer -->
        <div class="floatFix"></div>

        <div id="thumbnails" >

            <div id="thumbContainerMarie">
                <a class="galleryLink" onclick="putPic141();">
                    <img class="landscape" src="assets/Images/MariePeterWeddingImages/KJ4V7314editthumb.jpg" width="100" alt="thumb" />
                </a>

                <a class="galleryLink" onclick="putPic142();">
                    <img class="portrait" src="assets/Images/MariePeterWeddingImages/MM_24083editthumb.jpg" width="100" alt="thumb" />
                </a>

                <a class="galleryLink" onclick="putPic143();">
                    <img class="landscape" src="assets/Images/MariePeterWeddingImages/MM_24089editthumb.jpg" width="100" alt="thumb" />
                </a>
```

JS:

```
 //Marie&PeterWeddingAlbum//
 function putPic141(){
document.getElementById('bigPicMarie').src = "assets/Images/MariePeterWeddingImages/Edited/KJ4V7314edit.jpg";
document.getElementById('captionText').innerHTML = 'IMG001';    
 }//end putPic141

 function putPic142(){
document.getElementById('bigPicMarie').src = "assets/Images/MariePeterWeddingImages/Edited/MM_24083edit.jpg";
document.getElementById('captionText').innerHTML = 'IMG002';    
 }//end putPic142
```

An example of what the gallery looks like: http://www.jamielouise.co.uk/portraits.html

What I want is a way of making the gallery generate automatically from all the images in a specified folder. Ideally I would like to it to appear and function in the same way as it does currently.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to read all images in a folder and create an array out of it. Solution in [Php read directory file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6628228/1287812).

It would be much easier if you had the full size images in one directory and the thumbnails in another. Otherwise, the array build up will have to detect files with the `thumb` suffix and act accordingly.

With the array at hand, do a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and print the HTML. Note that single and double quotes [have different uses in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/1287812).

```php
/* Supposing an array like */
$images = array( 
       array( 'thumb' => 'thumb1url', 'full' => 'full1url' ), 
       array( 'thumb' => 'thumb2url', 'full' => 'full2url' ) 
);

echo '<div id="thumbContainerMarie">' . "\r\n";
$id_num = 1;
foreach( $images as $img )
{
    printf(
        '<a class="galleryLink" id="%s" onclick="%s"><img class="landscape" src="%s" width="100" alt="thumb" /></a>', 
        'galLink' . $id_num,
        "putPic('" . $img['full'] . "');",
        $img['thumb']
    );
    echo "\r\n";
    $id_num++;
}
echo '</div>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function putPic( url )
{
    alert( url );
}
</script>
```

This creates the following HTML. Note the use of only one JS function with the value we need being passed to it:

```
<div id="thumbContainerMarie">
<a class="galleryLink" id="galLink1" onclick="putPic('full1url');"><img class="landscape" src="thumb1url" width="100" alt="thumb" /></a>
<a class="galleryLink" id="galLink2" onclick="putPic('full2url');"><img class="landscape" src="thumb2url" width="100" alt="thumb" /></a>
</div>
<script>etc...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick and detailed response. I can quite easily seperate the thumbs and full sized images into seperate folders. Would doing this significantly simplify the solution?

Comment: Yes, if the files are split into dirs, they can have the same name so you don't have to worry about this. The array will be a simple one and it's just a matter of changing the path.

Comment: Hi sorry quite new to PHP, could you advise me where the above needs to be put? Also what would the array function be assuming thumbs in a directory named "marie&peterthumbs" and full sized in "marie&peterimages"

Comment: Create a simple PHP file `test.php` and go testing the code and the output it produces. After you get how it works, place the code in your `gallery.php` file after `<div id="thumbnails">`